# How to cancel a Paypal Order after user approvation? (API v2)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, paypal

I'm actually trying to create an application that use Papal API v2.

I succesfully create the oreder and get money on sandbox.
I use JS Paypal method *onApprove* to call order.capture to get the order and create the subscription on my systems.
But if there are some issue on my serverside code, how i can block the order on paypal API to stop get money from user if something going bad?

```
        paypal.Buttons({
            locale: 'it_IT',
            style: {
                shape: 'pill',
                color: 'blue',
                layout: 'vertical',
                label: 'buynow',
                fundingicons: 'true',
            },
            createOrder: function (data, actions) {
                return actions.order.create(my_PlanOrderDef);
            },
            onApprove: function (data, actions) {
                console.log(data)
                console.log(actions)
                return actions.order.capture().then(function (details) {
                    if (!CloseProcess(details)) {
                        console.log("FAIL! HERE SOMETHING GOING BAD ON MY LOGIC, AND I NEED TO CANCEL THE ORDER PAYMENT");
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            },
            onError: function (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        }).render('#btnPaypalContainer');
```

CloseProcess method just call my serverside logic to create a subscription on my system.
I probably miss something in paypal v2 logics so apologize me, any idea to accomplish this task?

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an order is created, it is valid for 72 hours.

When an order becomes approved, it is valid for 3 hours.

There is no method to cancel an order.

If you don't wish to use an order, discard its id and do not capture it.

---

To change to a server-side integration for order creation and capture, follow the [Set up standard payments](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/set-up-standard-payments/) guide and make 2 routes on your server, one for 'Create Order' and one for 'Capture Order', [documented here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/#server-side-api-calls). Both routes should return only JSON data (no HTML or text). Inside the 2nd route, when the capture API is successful you should store its resulting payment details in your database (particularly `purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0].id`, which is the PayPal transaction ID) and perform any necessary business logic (such as sending confirmation emails or reserving product) immediately *before* forwarding your return JSON to the frontend caller.

Pair those 2 routes with the frontend approval flow: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

Comment: Hello, 
thank you for clarification, for me it is not complete clear what happen if something going wrong after buyer approvation.
I see in sandbox, after user approvation, the order payment is processed and completed instantly.

But if something going wrong on my system after paypal approvation window is closed, and i cant process order for tecnical reasons, there is no way clientside to stop paypal get money from buyer.

Is that ok?

Comment: The payment is not processed and completed automatically after approval. It is only completed after capture. So, do not capture immediately if you do not want it to be completed immediately. A server-side creation and capture is the most robust solution, for which you need to stop using `actions.order.create()` and stop using `actions.order.capture()` and change to a server-side REST API integration. Update answer with those details.

Comment: It's not clear what is causing `CloseProcess(details)` to fail in your example, but that logic can happen before the capture.  Alternatively, if that logic must happen only after a successful capture, then when that logic fails you will need to refund the payment.

Comment: Thank you, 
usually nothing bad happens in CloseProcess, but that method comunicate serverside the payment was approved by user, and so it create the order in my database.
Anyway if something going bad during order creation i was thought i can stop the order capture on clientside.

Comment: My idea was to process the order on serverside, but reading v2 API documentation i thought i can do the creation of order ONLY clientside via Javascript,  Paypal documentation is a bit unclear for me.
Anyway, if i completly undrstood your reply, the fastest solution is :
onApprove: function (data, actions) {
                    if (!CloseProcess()) {
                        console.log("FAIL")
                        return false;
                    } else {
                        return actions.order.capture().then(function (details) {});
                    }
                },

Comment: The client-side-only JavaScript solution basically exists for people who are not capable of integrating server-side.  Server-side is recommended anytime you need to do something important with the result, such as writing to a database.  Client-side-only will work, but is not as robust of a solution.

Comment: Thank you for you patience,
usually this is my approach, but it is a bit unclear for me how call Paypal on serverside in order to create the order and capture it. 
This process was clear in API v1 (Just calling a Webservice with various methods gived from API) but not in v2 (a mix of JS and Webservice calls?).  
The link you gave me above, looking pure Javascript calls, but i'm probably confused because i'm working in ASP.NET Forms.

Comment: The JS approval flow is client-side and will call your server routes, located at whatever you sub in to '/demo/checkout/api/paypal/order/create/' as the path on your server. Those paths will be ASP.net code which create and capture an order, respectively, and return/output JSON with the result

Comment: Thank You, 
Very usefull explanation.
Really Appreciated.